# импортирование функции из другого файла

Tags: python

a.py

```
import b
hello = ("bye")

def hello():
    inputa = input("hi")
    if input a == 'hi':
        b.goodbye()
```

b.py

```
import a
bye = ("hello")

def goodbye():
    inputb = input("bye")
    if input inputb == 'bye':
        a.hello()
```

при запуске любого кода и вводе hi или bye выводит ошибку

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
partially initialized module 'b' has no attribute 'goodbye' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

пробовал переназывать файлы, функции, но ничего не помогает

Comment: most likely due to a circular import - это цикличный импорт, нельзя одновременно за импортить два файла друг в друга, попробуйте from b import goodbye

Comment: + и что значит `при запуске любого кода` ?

Comment: имеется ввиду любого из двух приведенных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Циклические импорты в питоне считаются ошибкой. Создайте еще файл main.py в который и вынесите логику вызова этих функций. Или сделайте один файл основным в который будет подгружаться все остальное. По логике обычно программа имеет одну точку входа (в вашем случае файл с запуска которого все начинается).
2. Для If не нужна доп конструкция input. Напишите лучше так:

```py
if inputb == 'bye':
```

Аналогично и для а.py